# JST time conversion takes unbelievably long in Python 3.8

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am new to python and I had a requirement to convert UTC to JST which I did but I also noticed that the code to convert UTC to JST takes a longer than expected.

Waiting for 5-7sec. just for the time-zone conversion is not good performance, following is the code that I am using:

```
self._to_timestamp = datetime.now(timezone(UTC)).astimezone(timezone(JST)).replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=0)
```

I believe I have made a mistake somewhere in conversion, it would be appreciated if anyone could spot the issue.

Answer (score 2):

how do you obtain the time zone settings? I'd suggest

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from dateutil.tz import gettz
from backports.zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9: just zoneinfo

UTC = timezone.utc
JST = gettz('Asia/Tokyo')
JST_z = ZoneInfo('Asia/Tokyo')

dt = datetime.now(UTC).astimezone(JST).replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=0)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 24, 19, 0, tzinfo=tzfile('Japan'))
```

...that runs relatively quick on my machine;

```
%timeit datetime.now(UTC).astimezone(JST).replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=0)
9.66 µs ± 415 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit datetime.now(UTC).astimezone(JST_z).replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=0)
2.18 µs ± 143 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

*Python 3.8.5 x64 on Windows 10*

Comment: I am using ```from pytz import timezone``` to get the timezone.

Comment: @vishwas: ok, although I'd suggest to not use pytz anymore since it's deprecated with the release of Python 3.9, this should work as well. Then what is `UTC` and `JST` in your code?

Comment: They are just strings, ```UTC = "UTC"``` and ```JST = "Asia/Tokyo"```

Comment: @vishwas: Ok thanks for the info. If I run this with pytz.timezone, it takes about 6 µs, so in-between the option using dateutil (slowest) and the option using zoneinfo (fastest). Did you try to run my code? You'll need an IPython console to call `%timeit`. But it shouldn't take seconds in any case.